# Unknown coordinate system produced in 1980 by Japanese company in North Philippines

Tags: coordinate-system, philippines

I am having the same difficulty with one of the report produced in 1980 by Japanese company. The grids format also N 38,578, E 41,400. The project is 390 kilometers north of Manila. I would like to know what is the coordinate system? What grids? what datum? and how convert them to WGS1984 UTM zone 51

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about the site.  At the moment your question does not have a question mark which is making what you are asking unclear.

Comment: Unless they dropped the leading digits, the coordinates don't match the Luzon 1911 TM zones, nor any UTM zones. I haven't been able to find any other possibilities.

Comment: Here is a link to a historical document on Phiippines coordinate systems: http://unstats.un.org/unsd/geoinfo/RCC/docs/rccap18/CRP/18th_UNRCCAP_econf.100_crp%2017.pdf  It looks like you may have your work cut out for you, since the Philippines did a major upgrade of their mapping system in the 1990s.

Comment: Maybe related, but still unresolved: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53086/unknown-old-coordinate-system-of-the-phillipines. Can you identify points in that coordinate system and Google Maps or Openstreetmap?

Comment: Hi AndreJ, 

That is the problem for me. I cannot relate those local points into WGS84 UTM 51. The only possible way was to visually align countours line to match the satellite basemap terrain.